# Cannot open Files and getting error code 0x80070002 on C

Tags: c

Hi i had a sample code for reading and writing on a txt file but visual studio wont read the code and keep crashing and giving same error 0x80070002 (error happens in bot "w" and "r" formats)
here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    FILE* fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("C:\Users\39351\source\repos\exercise\prova.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        exit(1); 
    else {
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) putchar(c);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

no matter the code when i use the fopen command even fopen_s it gives this error
can someone help?

Comment: `\ ` is an [escape character in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). Use this: `"C:\\Users\\39351\\source\\repos\\exercise\\prova.txt"`

Comment: Of use forward slashes, which work on most normal paths in Windows (and have done since the DOS days).

Comment: i did same error :(

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to catch the crash? Where in your code does the crash happens?

Comment: it happens when it tries to read the if block which is the fopen command

Comment: Is your program crashing, or is Visual Studio itself crashing?

Comment: the program crashed but i found out it was access issue when trying to open the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use '/' istead '\'

you can change the location of the file, it may be a permission failure

Comment: Please add more details and attach a code snippet to provide more information for community

Answer (score 2):

The backslash (`\`) character introduces an escape sequence in C string literals, so it's trying to process the `\U`, `\3`, `\s`, `\r`, `\e`, and `\p` as escape sequences. For example, `\r` translates to a carriage return character. To fix this you need to double up the backslash characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    FILE* fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\39351\\source\\repos\\exercise\\prova.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        exit(1); 
    else {
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) putchar(c);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried the double slash thing same error

Comment: Does the directory `C:\Users\39351\source\repos\exercise` exist? If opening the file with `"w"` (write) access fails it indicates that either the directory doesn't exist or you don't have permission to create a file there. If `fopen` fails when opening for `"r"` (read) access it indicates that either the directory doesn't exist, the file doesn't exist, or you don't have permission to read the file.

Comment: the file exists alright but im guessing it was access issue